# Ansible: build a Mac Adresse from a string

Tags: python, ansible, mac-address

Ansible Noob here.

I have a string and I need to build a specific `MAC format`.

- string i got: `1a2b3c4e5f6g`
- string i need: `1a:2b:3c:4e:5f:6g`

​

I have a method that works but maybe there is a easier way.
I write the string in a `tempfile` and start a `python` script and save the output in a variable.

python code in my script that builds the format.

```
mac="%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s" %(mac\[0:2\],mac\[2:4\],mac\[4:6\],mac\[6:8\],mac\[8:10\],mac\[10:12\])
```

​

Is there a way where i can do this in the playbook and not with `tempfile` and `python` script ?

Comment: ``1a:2b:3c:4e:5f:6g`` is not valid MAC. **g** is not hexadecimal number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do pretty much the same thing in your Ansible playbook. Because there is no `tuple` filter in jinja templates, it's easier to use the string `.format(...)` method rather than `%` style formatting:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    macaddr: "5281a421770f"

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        modified_macaddr: "{{ '{}{}:{}{}:{}{}:{}{}:{}{}:{}{}'.format(*macaddr) }}"

    - debug:
        var: modified_macaddr
```

This will output:

```
TASK [debug] *************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "modified_macaddr": "52:81:a4:21:77:0f"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [hwaddr](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html#mac-address-filter) filter. For example

```
  vars:
    macaddress: '1a2b3c4d5e6f'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ macaddress|hwaddr('unix') }}"
```

gives

```
msg: 1a:2b:3c:4d:5e:6f
```